# How to set redis cache prefix key for non spring boot java application using xml configuration

Tags: java, spring-data-redis, redis-cache, wildfly-18

I would like to set a custom cache key prefix for my application which uses xml configuration for my RedisCacheManager, my goal is, if the cache key is student-detail, the cache key should be test :: student-detail or prod :: student-detail, I have already set usePrefix to true, but I cant find a way to define the actual key value. Here below an extract of my cacheManager configuration.

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
      c:redisOperations-ref="redisTemplate"
      c:defaultExpiration=3600
      c:usePrefix="true">
</bean>
```

For the information, I know in spring boot is as simple as setting a property in the application properties as :

```
spring.cache.redis.key-prefix=some::
spring.cache.redis.use-key-prefix=true
```

Just to put some context why I precised for non spring boot java application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create your custom redis cache prefix by implementing RedisCachePrefix.See the code below

```
package com.cache.custom.utils;

import com.morgan.design.properties.ReloadableProperty;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCachePrefix;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

public class MyRedisCachePrefix implements RedisCachePrefix {
/** The Prefix */
@ReloadableProperty("prefixString")
private String personalPrefixString;

/** The key string redis serializer */
@Autowired
String StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer;

/** The delimiter */
private final String delimiter = "::";

@Override
public byte[] prefix(String cacheName) {
  return stringRedisSerializer.serialize(personalPrefixString.concat(":").concat(cacheName).concat(this.delimiter));
}
}
```

Then on the xml :

```
<bean id=stringRedisSerializer"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
<bean id="redisCachePrefix"
      class="com.cache.custom.utils.MyRedisCachePrefix"/>
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
      c:redisOperations-ref="redisTemplate"
      p:defaultExpiration=3600
      p:usePrefix="true"
      p:cachePrefix-ref="redisCachePrefix"
>
</bean>
```

N.B : personalPrefixString value will be taken from properties files entry of prefixString.
If prefixString value is testing and cacheName is student-details-cache then your cache key will be prefixed by : testing:student-details-cache::